# Following function must return true if given sequence is valid. Why this function doesn't return true for "||" sequence?

Tags: javascript, sequence

Function must return true for "()" sequence and false for "[)" sequence, so it does. But why this function doesn't return true for "||" sequence? Could you help, please?

I wrote this code, but nothing works :(

```
function check(s) {
  const brackets = {
    ")": "(",
    "]": "[",
    "}": "{",
    "|": "|",
  };
  const st = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (isClosedBracket(s[i])) {
      if (brackets[s[i]].toString() !== st.pop()) {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
      st.push(s[i]);
    }
  }
  return st.length === 0;
}
//if bracket is in this array, function returns true, so bracket is closing
function isClosedBracket(ch) {
  return [")", "]", "}", "|"].indexOf(ch) > -1;
}
```

Comment: As a general advice, instead of in-place expressions, try using named variables more often. This improves code readability (and “understandability”), so you don’t have these kinds of questions in the future.

Comment: `|` does not have a direction ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the pipe sequence "||" uses the same character for opening and closing, then when the first | (the opening one) will be encountered, the block of code for the closing bracket will be executed.

Your code works, but it will not operate correctly if the opening character is the same as the closing character. If you absolutely need this feature, then consider adding more checks in this particular situation.

However, the code will get much more complex since a singular | could also mean a closing bracket in an error sequence, so inputs like "(|)" will be a bit complicated to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all! I solved this problem by adding another if/else block. Here is solution, if you need it =3

```
function check(str) {
 let stack = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
   if (
     +str[i] === 1 ||
     +str[i] === 3 ||
     +str[i] === 5 ||
     str[i] === "(" ||
     str[i] === "[" ||
     str[i] === "{"
   ) {
     stack.push(str[i]);
   } else if (
     (+str[i] === 2 && stack.at(-1) === "1") ||
     (+str[i] === 4 && stack.at(-1) === "3") ||
     (+str[i] === 6 && stack.at(-1) === "5") ||
     (str[i] === ")" && stack.at(-1) === "(") ||
     (str[i] === "]" && stack.at(-1) === "[") ||
     (str[i] === "}" && stack.at(-1) === "{")
   ) {
     stack.pop();
   } else if (str[i] !== stack.at(-1)) {
     stack.push(str[i]);
   } else {
     stack.pop();
   }
 }

 return !stack.length > 0;
}
```

Any ideas how to improve this code?